# executeScalar on stored procedure

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc

I just want to se if my stored procedure selects any rows.

```
 using (var conn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(
                  "Data Source=DANIEL-DATOR;Initial Catalog=EvaluationTest;Integrated    Security=True"))
        using (var command = new SqlCommand("countRecords", conn))
        {
            conn.Open();
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@usermail", prop.Sendmail));
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            int userCount = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
            conn.Close();


            if (userCount > 0)
            {
                return 1;
            }

                return 2;
```

i get this error from the code: System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

ExecuteScalar will return null if the set of results is empty; bear in mind that the way this function works is that it takes the value of the first column of the first row of the returned data.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx

It must be the case that your Stored Procedure is not returning anything at all; so you should check if the result is null:

```
var result = command.ExecuteScalar();
if (result!=null)
{
    //you got some data
     Int32.TryParse(result.ToString, out userCount);
     return user Count>0?1:2;
}
```